# How do I check an input for an integer in Python?

Tags: python, input

I used:

```
day = int(input('Please input the day you were born: e.g 8th=8 21st = 21 : '))
month = int(input('Please input the month you were born: e.g may = 5 december = 12 : '))
year = int(input('Please input the year you were born: e.g 2001 / 1961 : '))

if day == int and month == int and year == int:
```

But it always even when it's an integer says it's wrong.

Comment: `type(day) is int` etc.

Comment: @axiom You should really use `isinstance`.

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: By virtue of wrapping your input calls in `int(`, your type checking becomes useless, because there are only two possibilities: 1) day, month, and year are all integers; or 2) your program crashed with a `ValueError` within the first 3 lines and the `if `will never run.

Comment: Could you give more detail about what "But it always even when it's an integer says it's wrong."?  What exactly is your wrong input and output?

Comment: @Kevin: Technically, in Python 2, the type might be `long` without a crash occurring. Of course, the odds that they really want to reject `long` is pretty small (and the fact that they're using `input` instead of `raw_input` points to this being Py3 code, but that's open to question; lots of people use `input` in Py2 when they shouldn't).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def get_int(p,error_msg="Thats Not An Int!"):
    while True:
         try:
            return int(raw_input(p))
         except (ValueError,TypeError):
            print "ERROR: %s"%error_msg

day = get_int('Please input the day you were born: e.g 8th=8 21st = 21 : ')
#day is guaranteed to be an int
```

I like to take this and abstract it further

```
 def force_type(type_class,prompt,error_msg):
     while True:
         try:
            return type_class(prompt)
         except (ValueError,TypeError):
            print error_msg
```

then it simply becomes

```
 def get_int(p,err_msg):
     return force_type(int,p,err_msg)
 def get_float(p,err_msg):
     return force_type(float,p,err_msg)
 ...
```

## allthat said if you want to typecheck you should ~*not*~ use `type(var)` you should use `isinstance(var,int)`

Comment: This isn't OOP enough. Can you make it more OOPy?

Comment: @MorganThrapp sure `def get_int(self,p,err_msg):` :P

Comment: is it possible for you to explain this to me

Comment: you try and convert it forever until a user enters valid input ... its python so if you just read it out loud it does a pretty good job of explaining itself

Comment: @benjiboi79 `get_int` tries to give you back the user's input (after casting to `int`). If it fails for whatever reason (like the user types something that isn't a number), it prints an error message and prompts the user to re-input.

Comment: @benjiboi79 the important thing is to realize that after you type `int(...)`, the result WILL BE AN `int`. You don't have to test for that again. If it fails to convert it to `int`, it will raise an exception (`ValueError` or maybe `TypeError`) and stop execution of your program. By the time your code gets to where you're testing if they're ints, they're *guaranteed* to be ints.

Answer (score 1):

To check type you can do:

```
type(aVar) is aType
```

Anyway, as Kevin said in a comment you're already wrapping input to int, so either it's actually an int or your program crashed

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if type(day) == int and type(month) == int and type(year) == int
```

Comment: But that will be a tautology. Given the rest of his code, `type(day)` will always be `int` whenever that line of code is executed.

Comment: yeah, but i just wanted to show how to access type of variable. dont know why he has declared all three variables as int, in which case there is no need to compare!

Comment: you're welcome! please upvote/accept the answer if you found it useful